# Growth equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Year 2003 there was approx. 10 % of a substance, the year 2013 the substance is 40 %
One modell which can describe the substance speed of growth is that the substance, increases every moment, is proportionate to the product of percent of substance and percentage of non-containing substance. After how many years from 2003 do we have 90 % of this substance?

Okey, I thought about this equation: $$y' = ys \to (ye^{-sx})' = 0 \to\  y = Ce^{sx} $$
We've got y(0) = 0.1 and y(10) = 0.4

I got y(x) to  $$y(x) = \frac{4e^{\frac{x}{10}}}{10}$$

And when I set y(x) = 0.9 and solve for x I get the wrong answer. The Answer should be $40  \frac {ln \ 3}{ln \ 6}$ years

Answer (score 1):

**A start:** The intended model is that the proportion $P$ of the substance at time $t$ satisfies a differential equation of the shape 
$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP(1-P),$$
where $k$ is a constant.

You can solve this DE by separation of variables. For information, search under *logistic equation*.

**Added:** When we solve the DE, we get, after simplification,
$$P(t)=\frac{P(0)}{P(0)+e^{-kt}(1-P(0))}.$$
 Use the fact that $P(0)=0.1$ and $P(10)=0.4$ to find $k$. Then set $P(t)$ equal to $0.9$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: Hmm... So should I use PQ? Because I'll get : $p - p^{2} -e^{kt} = 0$ I am sayin this because we don't use logistic equations :/

Comment: The language is not completely clear, but the description is very much of the logistic (Verhulst) equation type. Separate variables, we get $\frac{dP}{P(1-P)}=k\,dt$. Integrate, using partial fractions on the left. Or use a canned formula for the general solution.

Comment: Hmmm will look in to it more :)